# Floating Point Arithmetic: Deriving Wobble

Tags: floating-point, precision, numerical-methods

I am going through David Goldberg's *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*. I have no formal background in numerical analysis and am having a hard time understanding the paper. In the section *Relative Error and Ulps*, he goes on to derive the upper-bound of the relative error when approximating a real number with the close FP number. So corresponding to **.5 ULPs**, when a real number is approximated by a FP number **d.ddd...d x β <sup>e</sup>**, the absolute error is  **((β/2)β<sup>-p</sup>) x β<sup>e</sup>**. He says that numbers of the form **d.ddd...d x β<sup>e</sup>** have values that range from **β<sup>e</sup> to β x β<sup>e</sup>**. I don't understand how this range comes from. To find the relative error, I need to divide by the actual real number that I am approximating. Why is he dividing by the values that the FP number can take? What am I missing?

Further, I am struggling to understand the significance of *wobble*. A few paragraphs later, he demonstrates this relationship by taking a real-number x and then approximating it with a FP number. Then finding the error in ULPs and in relative. Then multiplies the real number by 8 (and the FP approximation as well). The error when measured in ULPs increases but the relative error remains the same.

Somehow I fail to develop an intuition for this relationship. Where is it useful?

Comment: When you refer to a document, please provide a complete citation, including version or edition identification (date, number, whatever), publication it appeared in, and a URL when available. This paper has been published in multiple versions, so people may need to know which edition you are referring to in order to see the context and find the exact passage.

Comment: I am sorry, the paper I am referring to is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So corresponding to .5 ULPs, when a real number is approximated by a FP number *d*.*ddd*...*d* x β<sup>*e*</sup>, the absolute error is ((β/2)β<sup>-*p*</sup>) x β<sup>*e*</sup>.

Not quite, it says when a real number is approximated by the closest floating-point number, the absolute error **can be as large as** ((β/2)β<sup>-*p*</sup>) x β<sup>e</sup>, not that it **is** that value.

> He says that numbers of the form *d*.*ddd*...*d* x β<sup>*e*</sup> have values that range from β<sup>*e*</sup> to β x β<sup>*e*</sup>. I don't understand how this range comes from.

That is because that first digit *d* is always some digit from 1 to β−1. If the first digit were 0, we would adjust the exponent *e* down one to bring more digits up. If there were two or more digits before before the radix point, we would adjust *e* up to push digits down. For example, we are not going to represent 12345 as .012345•10<sup>6</sup> or as 12.345•10<sup>3</sup>; we use 1.2345•10<sup>4</sup>. The significand in Goldberg’s format is always at least one and less than β. Since the significand *S* satisfies 1 ≤ *S* < β, the (positive) number represented satisfies 1•β<sup>*e*</sup> ≤ *S* < β•β<sup>*e*</sup>.

> Further, I am struggling to understand the significance of *wobble*.

Consider all the real numbers between 10,000 (inclusive) and 100,000 (exclusive). With a base-10 five-digit floating-point, these all have an ULP of 1. When we convert 10,000.7 to this format, the closest number is 10,001, so the absolute error is .3, the ULP error is .3, and the relative error is .3 / 10,000.7 ≈ 2.9998•10<sup>−5</sup>. When we convert 99,000.7 to this format, the closest number is 99,001, so the absolute error is .3, the ULP error is .3, and the relative error is .3 /99,000.7 ≈ 3.03•10<sup>−6</sup>. So the ULP error is the same, but the relative error is nearly ten times less. Conversely, a relative error of about 3•10<sup>−5</sup> is .3 ULP just above 10,000 but 3 ULP just below 100,000.

When we convert 100,007 to this format, the closest representable number is 100,010, so the absolute error is 3, the ULP error is .3, and the relative error is back to 2.9998•10<sup>−5</sup>. This is what Goldberg means by the relative error wobbling relative to the ULP error. Within a fixed exponent interval, the ULP is a fixed amount. Over a large exponent range, the ULP error approximates the relative error; it changes with the same **average** that the relative error does, but it does so in jumps, whereas the relative error is continuous.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Shouldn't this be 1•β^e <= S < β•β^e? 1•β^e exactly represents the real number 1•β^e?

The real number represented can be equal to (β-1.0000...00) x β^e but never equal to β•β^e (always less than it). Why is there an equality in the relation then, in the paper? As I understand it, the relative error can never be equal to the machine epsilon.

Comment: @PrashantPandey: Yes, that was a typo. I have changed “<” to “≤”.